# Fazer if negando um booleano no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, booleano

Como eu faço para o `if` verificar uma negação de um booleano, como abaixo:

```
self.senha = Gugu_0099

    for i in self.senha:
         if i.isdigit() and i.isalpha():
               total_simbolos += 1
```

Eu quero que entre nesse `if` se o caractere não for nem número e nem do alfabeto.
Quando estudava PHP era possível usar exclamação para mostrar negação, por exemplo:
`!i.isdigital()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta utilizar o `not`.

```py
condition = False

if not condition:
  print('Entrou no if')
```

Comment: Eu estava com um problema parecido,e isso também me ajudou!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
if not (u0 <= u <= u0+step):
    u0 = u0+ step # change the condition until it is satisfied
else:
    do sth. # condition is satisfied
```

é apenas um exemplo de if, é só você adequar as condições do if.